# Error in Turtle: AttributeError: 'RawTurtle' object has no attribute 'delay'

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas, ttk, messagebox

root = CTk()
root.geometry('1080x680')
root.title('Tecnologia')
root.set_appearance_mode('dark')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1080, height=480)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

def tricmd():
    t.home()
    t.speed(1)
    t.forward(150)
    t.left(120)
    steps.configure(text='Explanation')
    t.delay(5)
    t.forward(150)
    t.left(120)
    steps.configure(text='Other explanation')
    t.delay(5)
    t.forward(150)
    t.left(120)

def squarecmd():
    t.home()
    t.speed(1)
    t.forward(150)
    t.left(90)

def pentacmd():
    t.home()
    t.speed(1)
    t.forward(150)
    t.left(45)

triangolo = CTkButton(root, width=50, height=35, text='Triangolo', command=tricmd)
triangolo.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20)
quadrato = CTkButton(root, width=50, height=35, text='Quadrato', command=squarecmd)
quadrato.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
quadrato = CTkButton(root, width=50, height=35, text='Pentagono', command=pentacmd)
quadrato.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=20)

steps = CTkLabel(root, text='Here is  explained the shape', width=10, height=30)
steps.grid(row=1, column=0)

def quit():
    root.destroy()
quitb = CTkButton(root, width=50, height=35, text='Esci', command=quit)
quitb.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make a tkinter interface that draws different shapes when you click the corresponding button and explains how to draw that shape. Only the triangle code is completed and it is returning the error mentioned in the title.
Is there a way to use .delay() with RawTurtle?

Comment: change turtle.delay(5) to t.delay(5) inside tricmd?

Comment: In the question I'm using t.delay(5)

Comment: Use `t.getscreen().delay(...)`.